# Derivative of real valued function w.r.t real valued variable

Tags: complex-analysis, chain-rule

Lets say we have a function $ h: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ that can be composed of two other functions $ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C $ and $ g: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb R $ in the following way $ h(x) = g(f(x)) $.

I want to compute the derivative: $ \frac{dh}{dx} $ but I only have the intermediate results: $ \frac{dh}{df} $ and $ \frac{df}{dx} $ which are both complex valued. How should I combine them to obtain the correct real valued $ \frac{dh}{dx} $ ?

I am familiar with the chain rule for differentation so I tried: $ \frac{dh}{dx} = \frac{dh}{df} \frac{df}{dx} $. This is however still a complex number. And taking the real part seems not correct.

Note:
A situation where this occurs is when you transform a real valued variable to the frequency domain via the fourier transform, then do some operation on it and transform it back to the spatial domain. If you want the derivative of the final result w.r.t. the input variable and want to compose it of derivatives of the intermediate results.

Comment: Can you provide the example where you tried $\frac{dh}{dx}$ through your computation and got a complex number?

Comment: Back to the definitions: $$f(x+u)=f(x)+f'(x)u+o(u)$$ and $$g(z+w)=g(z)+g'(z)w+o(w)$$ when $u\to0$ and $w\to0$, hence $$h(x+u)=g(f(x)+f'(x)u+o(u))=g(f(x))+g'(f(x))f'(x)u+o(u)$$ and indeed $$h'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x)$$ which must be real if $h$ is real valued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this, instead of dealing with $f$ as a complex number, treat it as a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.  In this case, the chain rule would tell you that

$$
\frac{dh}{dx}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial f_1}\cdot\frac{df_1}{dx}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial f_2}\cdot\frac{df_2}{dx}.
$$

In your case, you should be able to do this via:
$$
\frac{dh}{dx}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\cdot\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{f}}\cdot\frac{d\overline{f}}{dx}.
$$

In other words, you must differentiate $g(z)$ with respect to both $z$ and $\overline{z}$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Indeed this seems the way to go. 

In my case, $ f $ is either purely real or purely imaginary. So I was wondering whether it is possible to express $ \frac{d\bar{f}}{dx} $ and $ \frac{dg}{d\bar{f}} $ in terms of $ \frac{d{f}}{dx} $ and $ \frac{dg}{df} $?

Comment: If $f$ is purely real or purely imaginary, then be careful about discontinuities in $f$.  It is rare that the holomorphic and anti-holomorphic parts of a function have nice relationships.  It depends on the structure of your particular problem whether you can simplify the expressions.

Comment: I think that $ f $ is totally holymorphic. $ f $ is the fourier transform of a gaussian derivative of order $ n $ and x plays the role of the $ \sigma $. So $ f $ is complex valued and $ \sigma $ is real valued. $ f $ is purely real or purely imaginary depending on the order of spatial derivative $ n $.

Comment: If $f$ purely real or purely imaginary, then you should be able to relate $\frac{df}{dx}$ to $\frac{d\overline{f}}{dx}$ as equal or negatives of each other.  The problem comes in $\frac{dg}{d\overline{f}}$ and $\frac{dg}{df}$.  You are taking the derivative at two different places when $f$ is purely imaginary, so unless $g$ has some symmetry, you're out of luck.

Comment: Does it help that both $ \frac{dg}{d\bar{f}} $  and $ \frac{d\bar{f}}{dx} $ are complex because they are fourier transforms of a real signal? Because of this they are both conjugate symmetric?

Appearently, for my case this solves it: $ \frac{dh}{dx} = \bar{\frac{df}{dx}} \frac{dg}{df}  $ Although I do not understand it. It probably has to with the symmetry in the signals. After all, the function $h$ maps a real scalar to a real scalar. But the intermediate results are complex vectors with a special type of symmetry.

Comment: You might have better luck if you start a new question, including the specific features of your problem.  The question above seems too general for your purposes, and, the comments don't give you enough characters to be truly specific about your problem.